# Merge [amd64] and [x64]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[amd64](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amd64) and [x64](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/x64) mean the same. On superuser they are synonyms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[amd64](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amd64) and [x64](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/x64) merged into [64-bit](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/64-bit)